# Where are the debug symbols for plasmashell (Kubuntu 19.04)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, debug

I'm having an issue with plasmashell crashing anytime I leave the computer alone for more than an hour or two.  I've tried installing debugging symbols to generate a useful crash report, but keep getting told I'm missing the symbols for '/usr/bin/plasmashell'.  I installed the package 'plasma-workspace-dbgsym', so I'm curious why I still don't have the debug symbols and where to get them?

Operating System: Kubuntu 19.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.56.0
Qt Version: 5.12.2
Kernel Version: 5.0.0-13-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 12 × AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
Memory: 15.7 GiB of RAM

I followed the directions here: https://wiki.kubuntu.org/DebuggingProgramCrash to manually install debug symbols for the various libraries the crash handler said I was missing, including 'plasma-workspace-dbgsym'.  However, the crash handler still says I am missing symbols for '/usr/bin/plasmashell', even though `dpkg -S '/usr/bin/plasmashell'` shows that plasma-workspace is the package for plasmashell.

Output of `apt-cache` and `apt show`:

```
$ apt-cache policy plasma-workspace
plasma-workspace:
  Installed: 4:5.15.4-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4:5.15.4-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4:5.15.4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$ apt show plasma-workspace-dbgsym
Package: plasma-workspace-dbgsym
Package-Type: ddeb
Version: 4:5.15.4-0ubuntu1
Auto-Built-Package: debug-symbols
Priority: optional
Section: debug
Source: plasma-workspace
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian/Kubuntu Qt/KDE Maintainers <debian-qt-kde@lists.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 83.6 MB
Depends: plasma-workspace (= 4:5.15.4-0ubuntu1)
Breaks: plasma-workspace-dbg (<= 4:5.5.5.1-1~~)
Replaces: plasma-workspace-dbg (<= 4:5.5.5.1-1~~)
Build-Ids: [I deleted the long hexadecimal list included here]
Download-Size: 80.0 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com disco/universe amd64 Packages
Description: debug symbols for plasma-workspace
```

The details from the crash handler (note the ?? for missing symbols): https://pastebin.com/9RB4ZDgZ.

If I click on the "list of files" link in the crash handler to see what packages need to be installed, only '/usr/bin/plasmashell' is now listed.

Comment: Re. "I've tried **installing debugging symbols** to generate a useful crash report, but keep **getting told** I'm missing the symbols for '/usr/bin/plasmashell'." Can you clarify what exactly you try and what exactly the system reports? If you are doing this via the terminal, please copy/paste the output here by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1143321/edit) using [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently the missing debug symbols has been a confirmed bug for almost 2 years now (see [bug #1701788](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/1701788)).  Would be nice if it could be fixed....

Comment: Another possibly relevant bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/1701788

Comment: Apparently, that issue should be updated, `plasma-workspace-dev/impish 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1~ubuntu21.10~ppa1 amd64
  Plasma Workspace for KF5 devel files
`

Answer (score -1):

This is not a bug, generating stacktrace is an expensive operation most end user never wants to do. So it is not installed by default on most distribution, including kubuntu.

To have stacktrace, you need to have the *-dev related packages for the apps you want stacktrace for. Along with the basic ones for the kf5 libs.

In this case `sudo apt install plasma-workspace-dev`

To list currently installed -dev packages

```
$ apt search "\\-dev" | grep installed | egrep "(plasma|kf5|kde)"
```

or the full list

```
$ apt search "\\-dev" | grep installed
```

Comment: The point is that there aren't even dbg packages available, even if the user does want them

Comment: well, it is available now.... thanks for the downvotes

Comment: Are you saying that the debug symbols are now in *-dev instead of *-dbgsym?  Is this documented somewhere?