# Manually compile and install debugging symbols for the recoll package?

Tags: debugging, apport, source-packages, gdb

I've got some crash files for [recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/)
from which I would like to extract a symbolic stack trace.
Unfortunately,
[there are no debug symbols](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=928157)
[available for this package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/recoll/+bug/1814973),
so my stack traces are mostly unhelpful.

The crash files are generated by apport for `/usr/bin/recoll`,
so I want to use [symbols from an external file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)
rather than compiling from source with debugging symbols
(because then I'd have to reproduce the crash).
Based on the build ID, I'd expect them to go under
`/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/7e/83e15f5cfae88cef2850e4a510f4d4849ae6b9.debug`:

```
$ file /usr/bin/recoll
/usr/bin/recoll: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=7e83e15f5cfae88cef2850e4a510f4d4849ae6b9, stripped
$ gdb
(gdb) show debug-file-directory
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug".
```

I know I could add to the `debug-file-directory`, something like this:

```
(gdb) set debug-file-directory /usr/lib/debug:/home/nathaniel/mysymbols
```

but I still need to compile the object file,
and I'm [having trouble finding sufficient documentation](https://people.debian.org/~osamu/maint-guide.html#dbg)
on how to do this with apt/dpkg.
Sure, I can use `apt-get source -b recoll` to download and build it,
but the build ID isn't the same and the final executable is still stripped.
I'm guessing this is because `-fdebug-prefix-map` isn't the same.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep recoll
$ apt-get source -b recoll
<snip>
./configure CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/nathaniel/apt-get-source/recoll/recoll-1.23.7=.
<snip>
$ file recoll-1.23.7/qtgui/recoll
recoll-1.23.7/qtgui/recoll: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=be2479236c840a60c71848f9d8257b68856f28f5, not stripped
$ file recoll-1.23.7/debian/recoll/usr/bin/recoll
recoll-1.23.7/debian/recoll/usr/bin/recoll: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=be2479236c840a60c71848f9d8257b68856f28f5, stripped
```

so my question is:

How can I manually compile and install the debugging symbols
for the recoll package on Ubuntu 18.04?

Related:

- [Where are the debug symbols for plasmashell (Kubuntu 19.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143321/where-are-the-debug-symbols-for-plasmashell-kubuntu-19-04)
- [OpenJDK - Installing JDK Debug Symbols manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150114/openjdk-installing-jdk-debug-symbols-manually)
- https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/symbols-on-linux-part-three-linux-versus-windows/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473506/gdb-core-dump-find-executable-by-build-id
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787534/debug-information-file-conventions-for-debian-ubuntu